# Bootstrap background image not filling up space when mobile

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to make a background image fill up (in height) when going mobile. When I make the browser smaller, it doesn't seem like my media queries are kicking in.

Here's what my css looks like:

```
#main {
    background-image:url(../images/cc.jpg); 
    height:650px; background-size:cover; 
    background-position:0 -210px; 
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

#main .row {
    margin-top:200px;
}


@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) {
  #footer {
    font-size:10px;
  }

    #main {
        background-image:url(../images/cc.jpg); 
        height:100%; 
        background-size:cover; 
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
    }

    #id{ margin-top:90px; }

    #main .row {
        margin-top:100px;
    }

}

@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 568px) and (orientation : landscape) { 
  #footer {
    font-size:10px;
  }

    #main {
        background-image:url(../images/cc.jpg); 
        height:100%; 
        background-size:cover; 
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
    }

    #id{ margin-top:90px; }

    #main .row {
        margin-top:100px;
    }



}
```

Here's the URL if you want to see what the page looks like:

http://www.gulflifehomes.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change to `background-position: center;` and that should do the trick. Also, you should try and one-line your code when possible `background: url(../images/cc.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;`.

Comment: Using shorthand syntax is almost always a matter of preference.

Comment: that definitely seemed to help, but when i shrink down, it still looks a little off as i'm shrinking smaller. Any ideas on how to deal with that?

Comment: @ShawnErquhart and a matter of fewer bytes over the wire.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `background-position` rule or reset it to 0 for mobile if you still want it in place for desktop.

You have a lot of repetitive code there. You could just do this:

```
#main {
    background-image:url(../images/cc.jpg);
    height:650px; background-size:cover;
    background-position:0 -210px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

#main .row { margin-top:200px; }

@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) {
  #footer { font-size:10px; }
  #main { background-position: 0; }
  #id{ margin-top:90px; }
  #main .row { margin-top:100px; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to test media queries on desktop, you should use **min-width or max-width** instead of min-device-width or max-device-width.

So do this:

```
@media only screen and (min-width : 320px) and (max-width : 480px)
```

min-device and max-device refers to the ACTUAL resolution of your screen (ie: 1280x800) instead of the size of your browser. This is why your media queries isn't kicking in when resizing browser and testing on your machine.

Comment: that didn't seem to make any difference :\

Comment: then that means the existing code isn't working for mobile (not mediaqueries issue). Take a look at Shawn's solution above

Comment: that's exactly what i had there. The solution provided by swordfish seemed to fix the issue on the small width. It's still a little buggy but getting closer!